# How to parse a string between two periods in Shell into three variables?

Tags: shell

In Shell, I need to parse a string that will consistently have three components divided by periods. The length will not be consistent.

Example given values:

```
1.0.5
11.5.13
0.12.0
```

I need to parse them into three variables. For a given value 1.0.5, I need:

```
major=1
minor=0
fix=5
```

I have seen a good example that apparently only works in bash, which I don't have bash as an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few options:

#### Use a heredoc

```
IFS=. read -r major minor fix <<EOF
$version
EOF
```

#### Change input field separator, assign to positional parameters using `set`

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=.
set -- $version
major=$1
minor=$2
fix=$3
IFS=$old_IFS
```

I prefer the first option, since it's shorter and doesn't affect the positional parameters.

Comment: Does IFS work with Shell? I thought it was bash only.

Comment: Yes, [IFS is a standard shell variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (see _2.5.3 Shell Variables_).

Comment: This is all helpful! If it's not obvious, I'm new to shell. In reading about heredoc, I'm wondering if my this will require using a file instead of a variable, especially considering seeing "EOF." I've already got a variable that is assigned the value of the version captured from a properties file. It isn't the only property in that file.

Comment: `EOF` is just a commonly-used marker for the start and end of a heredoc. You can use `<<COOGIE` and end with `COOGIE` if you prefer. You don't need to use a file.